# how to include multiple Except Blocks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, try-catch

so i have the following code to scape info from amazon website.

now there are three prices, Every page does have a Title ( So no Problem there)

price one is the regular price

price 2nd is the deal price

price 3rd (There is no price)

I can get the First two by doing an except block but cant get the third, i tried putting finally but got everything Not Available. Here is the Code

```
for links in t:
 r = s.get(links)
 r.html.render(sleep=1,timeout=20)
 title = r.html.find("span.a-size-large.product-title-word-break",first=True).text
 
 try:
  price = r.html.find("span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.priceBlockBuyingPriceString",first=True).text.replace("₹","").replace(",","")
 except:
  price = r.html.find("span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.priceBlockDealPriceString",first=True).text.replace("₹","").replace(",","")
 finally:
  price = "Not Available"
  
 Final = {"title": title,"price": price}
 a.append(Final)

A = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(A)
```

Comment: Except blocks only run if the try block fails. Finally blocks run regardless of the result of the try and except blocks. So with this code, price will always be "Not Available."  Inside an except block, you can put another try/except.

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick reply, so i should have one more except block and inside that except block, i should do a try and except block correct ??

Comment: I don’t know what the structure of the website you’re crawling is, so I don’t really know. But it seems that you should have a try/except in the except block instead of a finally block

Answer (score 0):

Everything is returned as "Not Available" because your try/except/finally block told it to.

**QUICK EXPLANATION:**

`try` will attempt the code

`except` will execute if any error appears in `try` block

`finally` will always execute after `except` block regardless of values

**SUGGESTED SOLUTION:**

If you don't know what price is available for each object, you should find which price is available first. So,

```
#try to get buy price
try:
    buy_price = r.html.find("span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.priceBlockBuyingPriceString",first=True).text.replace("₹","").replace(",","")
except:
    buy_price = "Not available"

#try to get deal price
try:
    deal_price = r.html.find("span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.priceBlockDealPriceString",first=True).text.replace("₹","").replace(",","")
except:
    deal_price = "Not available"
```

Then after you know which price is available, you can add it to your dictionary by checking the type of the variable.

```
price = ''

if type(buy_price) == 'float':
    price = buy_price
elif type(deal_price) == 'float':
    price = deal_price
else:
    price = "Not Available"

Final = {"title": title,"price": price}
a.append(Final)
```